# How to deploy a .war stored in Google cloud storage to a Compute Engine VM instance using a Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

My current Approach-

I'm currently using Cloud Build to build and store a .war artifact in a GCS bucket. To deploy it on my custom VM, I'm running a java program on this GCE vm which detects changes to the bucket using Pub/Sub notification and downloads and deploys the fresh .war on the vm.

My Objective-

- Download a ~50MB Spring boot 2.X + Java 11 war from GCS using a cloud function written in Java 11
- Upload it to the VM(Ubuntu 18.04.x LTS) using cloud function(Generation not relevant)
- Deploy it on the VM from the cloud function(The war has an embedded tomcat container, so I only have to java -jar it)

My issue-

Connecting to the VM "externally" is my main issue. The only solution I can think of is running a Spring web service endpoint on the vm which receives a .war using POST. I'll use the cloud function to POST the downloaded .war to this endpoint which will deploy it on the vm.

However, this approach seems like a Rube Goldberg machine from my perspective so I'm wondering if there is better idea than what I've come up with.

P.S- We're aware that pulling from the VM is the more sound approach, but this cloud function deployment is a client request so sadly, we must abide.

Comment: Is your goal to download the .war file in Functions and somehow copy it to Compute Engine? Edit your question with details on what your objective is.

Comment: What do you mean by **copy it to the VM using  Cloud Function**? Do you mean download from Cloud Storage to the function and then copy the file to the VM? How large is the file? What is the operating system running on the VM? Have looked into how you will connect to your VM to transfer data? Your question lacks details. Edit your question with exactly what you are trying to do. Include the environment of both Functions and the VM. Details will make a big difference and in some cases, it will not be possible. Tip: don't do this as having the VM pull/download a file is much easier.

Comment: You have a couple of options. The HTTP POST command is one. Your process will then need to know what to do with the file plus you need to implement security. I would not implement that option. The next option is to use SSH from the function. You can copy the file to the VM and then execute commands. SSH provides security. There are SSH libraries for Java. Again I would not use this option. The next option is for the function to call an HTTP endpoint on the VM and have the VM download and install the .war file. I might use this option except ...

Comment: The correct option is to use the webhooks that Cloud Build provides to notify your VM to pull the new .war file.

Comment: John, could you please elaborate about the Cloud build webhook? . In Cloud build documentation the only webhook related article I found was a webhook based trigger for Cloud Build.

Comment: I should have called it a Cloud build **step** instead of webhook (I work with GitHub also). In the step you use **gcloud** to connect to your VM and run a script that does the pull of the .war. Example: `gcloud compute ssh <instance-name> --zone=<instance-zone> --command='/bin/sh /scripts/mycommand.sh'`

Comment: I am not sure what platform/runtime you are using for Cloud Function, but you can achieve this with [SCP](https://pypi.org/project/scp/) using python. Moreover, there is [GCLOUD](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) command available for the same. Or another option you can use is Cloud Run rather than Function, which runs a container, and with that you can do the copy and other stuff by running some script or something else within it.